# Iterate through list in nested list - Python

Tags: python, list, loops, nested

I have a long list with nested lists with each list consisting of multiple xy-coordinates.
In short, my lists looks like this

```
MyList = [ [ [1, 2], [1, 2] ], [ [1, 2], [1, 2] ], [ [1, 2], [1, 2] ]...]]]
```

I would like to extract all the "1's" to one variable, and all the "2's" to one variable.
So extract first element to a new list, and extract second element to another new list.
I have tried

```
for list in MyList:
   for newList in list:
      number1 = [item[0] for item in newList]
      number2 = [item[1] for item in newList]
```

Which gave me the error "int object is not subscriptable".
I also tried

```
def Extract(MyList):
   return list(list(zip(*MyList))[0])
```

Lastly I tried to just print the "1's" out to see if it would work

```
print(MyList[:][:][0])
output: [[1, 2], [1, 2]]
```

Comment: you data is build as three level of lists. and you are using three levels of for loops. so why are you using square brackets in the third level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
flatlist = [el for lst1 in MyList for lst2 in lst1 for el in lst2]
number1, number2 = flatlist[0::2], flatlist[1::2]
```

First you flat the list, and then you split it into two lists with alternating elements.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like so:

```py
>>> a = MyList
>>> x = [a[i][j][0] for i in range(len(a)) for j in range(len(a[i]))]
>>> x
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> y = [a[i][j][1] for i in range(len(a)) for j in range(len(a[i]))]
>>> y
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

You're basically iterating over each tuple of coordinates and take the X coordinate (`[0]`), respectively the y coordinate (`[1]`).

There might be better ways, this is the quick one I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can handle this with three for loop if time complexity is not an issue:

```
one = []
two = []
for item in MyList:
   for arr in item:
      for num in arr:
         if num == 1:
            one.append(num)
         else:
            two.append(num) 

# [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
# [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```